# What should the input parameter structure look like in validate(touple) function of Seaport contract?

Tags: contract-invocation, opensea

I'm trying to call the validate() method of Seaport but can't find the correct form of inputs, as it always returns the error `types/value length mismatch` when calling on Etherscan.

I'm calling the function `validate((tuple,bytes)[])` on [Seaport contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x00000000006c3852cbef3e08e8df289169ede581) with the following parameters:

```
[
 [ 
  [
   "0x06a9dCee089865cd6708C6C72c8EbF30cfd2750e", 
   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
   2, 
   "0x2ba0c22b0ddcd8f2ed67c1acd9cde3547e9cd968",
   52, 
   1,
   1, 
   0, 
   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
   0, 
   97500000000000,  
   97500000000000, 
   "0x06a9dCee089865cd6708C6C72c8EbF30cfd2750e", 
   0,   
   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",  
   0,  
   2500000000000,   
   2500000000000, 
   "0x0000a26b00c1F0DF003000390027140000fAa719",  
   1, 
   1677840888,  
   1677950888, 
   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
   68982005527218464,
   "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
   0 
   ], 
  "0x"
  ] 
 ]
```

Example of a working transaction: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x078594694f15565fcb16c68d2918950457e24ff7f12b8d60fb4cbf4df2861a65

Answer (score 0):

What I did wrong was that I didn't set brackets for every struct included. The correct structure would be:

```
[
 [ 
  [
   "0x06a9dCee089865cd6708C6C72c8EbF30cfd2750e", 
   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
   [
    [
     2, 
     "0x2ba0c22b0ddcd8f2ed67c1acd9cde3547e9cd968",
     52, 
     1,
     1
    ]
   ],
   [
    [
      0, 
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      0, 
      97500000000000,  
      97500000000000, 
      "0x06a9dCee089865cd6708C6C72c8EbF30cfd2750e"
    ],
    [
      0,   
      "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",  
      0,  
      2500000000000,   
      2500000000000, 
      "0x0000a26b00c1F0DF003000390027140000fAa719"
    ]
   ],
   1, 
   1677840888,  
   1677950888, 
   "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
   68982005527218464,
   "0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
   0 
   ], 
  "0x"
  ] 
 ]
```